# Приём ответа LiqPay (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Отправка данных работает, покупка тоже, но, к сожалению, обработка(callback) работает только если после оплаты нажать "Вернуться на сайт"

В роутах: `post '/liqpay_payment' => 'payments#liqpay_payment'`, контроллер с этим методом присутствует.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно включить в личном кабинете ликпей отправлять колбэк с POST data, там есть галочка.